# How to read BLOB from oracle db?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, blob

I'm trying to read BLOB data in the form of string from oracle db using sql developer.

This is the query that I'm using :

```
 select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(BLOB_COL,2000)) from BLOB_TABLE where BLOB_ID= 997600;
```

But the output what I get is machine readable format and not text.
Any suggestions on how to change this query?

Comment: may help to tell us how you're pulling it.. using sql developer or.... i know from php i had trouble with blobs using PDO but switching api's helped..

Comment: you can just do select * from table...we have a blob editor that can auto-preview pictures or display text OR send the files to the editor/program of choice http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the query, just query the BLOB column.

Double click on the cell.

Check the 'text' value.

Voila.

[image: i didnt run a query, just browsed the table directly]

[image: the actual text]